# Pegar elementos por class/id com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

No jQuery, usamos aspas pra pegar `$('div.oi')`. E no JavaScript puro? Piss se usarmos sem aspas é diferente.

Se formos mudar o css por exemplo: Com jQuery:

```
$('teste').css(teste);
```

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta já foi feita antes aqui na rede

Comment: Teria o link, Marcelo? Desculpe, não achei.

Comment: Uma coisa é pegar id, outra o class, id é um elemento único em uma pagina, já o class pode ter quantos elementos for necessário

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O jeito moderno em JS puro é:

```
// Para um elemento, por seletor
var el = document.querySelector('div.oi');

// Para múltiplos elementos
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div.oi');

// Para um elemento por ID, da maneira tradicional:
var el = document.getElementById('id_aqui');
```

Tanto `querySelector` quanto `querySelectorAll` podem ser aplicados tanto ao document, quanto a um elemento específico (para pegar descendentes dele).

Existem ainda outros métodos, como `getElementsByClassName`, que precisam ser utilizados em browsers mais antigos.

#### Referências

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)
- [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: No caso, no JQuery pode pega id e class com o $('  '), ja no JavaScript puro é diferente. Certo?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a diferença do querySelector e do querySelectorAll. Sei que All é todos, mas como assim? Quando eu usar o querySelector vai pegar só 1? Como assim 1?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o querySelectorAll vai retornar um array com os elementos, já o querySelector retorna um único elemento.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Com `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` você pode buscar por seletor como no jQuery (mas o jQuery aceita uns seletores a mais). Portanto, dá pra buscar por id com querySelector também, como em `var el = document.querySelector('#meuId')`. Sobre a diferença entre os 2 métodos, é o que o Marconi explicou.